# how to configure sphinx to use local mathjax

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

I'm having some trouble getting Sphinx to build pages with a local mathjax library. In the documentation [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/math.html#confval-mathjax_path), it says just to add the following `mathjax_path = "MathJax-2.7.4/MathJax.js"` to `conf.py`, but after building the files, I still get `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

Is there something else I need to do, besides run `make html` to get the configuration to load?

I just added the `mathjax_path = "MathJax-2.7.4/MathJax.js"` to the end of my conf.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that Sphinx doesn't rebuild your files unless your `.rst` source files changed. Because the configuration file doesn't touch the `.rst` files, it won't cause a rebuild. I ended up just removing all the files from the build directory and letting it recreate all the files.

Comment: Try `make clean html` which will clean the build directory then build HTML docs.