# Problem Rending Mathjax in github.io page generated from Sphinx

Tags: python, github-pages, python-sphinx, mathjax

I'm writing docs for [my python project](https://github.com/MagedMohamedTurk/Turbomachinery-Rotors-Balancing/tree/docs-sphinx) using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

This is my [conf.py](https://github.com/MagedMohamedTurk/Turbomachinery-Rotors-Balancing/blob/docs-sphinx/docs/source/conf.py)

The math renders just fine on local host but when deployed on [github.io](https://magedmohamedturk.github.io/Turbomachinery-Rotors-Balancing/html/primer.html#primer), it seems to be not working.

**On Local Host**
[image: On Local host]

**On github.io**
[image: On github.io]

Note: I added empty .nojekyll file to be able to use Sphinx templates.

I have no idea what might cause `githubpages` not to render `mathjax` even though it renders find on local machine.

Any ideas???

UPDATE: I got the math rendered when I allow `insecure content` in `chrome` browser.

[image]

What can be the problem?!!

Comment: Does it work with `mathjax_path = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72931039/407651

Comment: I tried and It didn't make any difference. I think if it were a problem in the `CDN` it wouldn't have rendered on either host or local. The math in my case renders on local machine but doesn't on `github.io`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the problem here with the help of [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157764/how-to-configure-sphinx-to-use-local-mathjax).

The problem when you need to deploy a `github.io` page using sphinx, the deployment of `github.com` looks for `index.html` file under `docs/` directly. Usually the case in `sphinx` is having the main `index.html` file under `docs/build/html/`.

So with the recommendation of some tutorial, I changed `conf.py` to build the `index.html` directly under `docs/` and this seems to be the problem that prevented `mathjax` from working.

When I restored `build/` folder and used a dummy [`index.html`](https://github.com/MagedMohamedTurk/Turbomachinery-Rotors-Balancing/blob/docs-sphinx/docs/index.html) that directs `github.io` to the real `index.html` inside `docs/build/html`, math is rendering fine now.

Answer (score 0):

in `conf.py`, try this:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    ]
```

and

```
mathjax_path = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. I already have `mathjax` in extensions, as I showed my `conf.py`. Trying different CDNs doesn't really make any difference. I have the math rendered in local server but it doesn't work on ['github.io'](https://magedmohamedturk.github.io/Turbomachinery-Rotors-Balancing/html/primer.html#primer)

Comment: ok, then you may have to resort to using a local version of mathjax. Here is how I handle plantUML:
`local_plantuml_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "_utility", "plantuml-1.2023.6.jar")
plantuml = f"java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar {local_plantuml_path}"`

You can customize that structure for your local version of mathjax. That *should* force interpretation on `github.io`